# Compiled mysql conflicts with already existing mysql

Tags: mysql

I have just installed mysql from source and used a paco wrapper
to see the file copy locations for "make install".
As per the paco log, I have the following :

```
/usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.a
/usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.so
/usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18
/usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18.1.0
/usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient_r.a
/usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so
/usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.18
/usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.18.1.0
/usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqld.a
/usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlservices.a
/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/adt_null.so
/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/auth.so
/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/auth_socket.so
/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/auth_test_plugin.so
/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/daemon_example.ini
/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/libdaemon_example.so
/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/mypluglib.so
/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/qa_auth_client.so
/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/qa_auth_interface.so
/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/qa_auth_server.so
/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/semisync_master.so
/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/semisync_slave.so
/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/validate_password.so
```

At this point I realized I didn't remove some old mysql debian packages before
the source code installation.
The output of the command :

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql
```

is below :

```
libdbd-mysql-perl               install
libmysqlclient18                install
mysql-client-5.5                install
mysql-client-core-5.5           install
mysql-common                    install
mysql-server                    install
mysql-server-5.5                install
mysql-server-core-5.5           install
```

Now I'm afraid there is conflict between the compiled package and the already installed
ones. Could anyone suggest a way to remove the already installed debian packages so that only the compiled package exists on the system?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: man dpkg and man apt-get will help you with that, I guess.

Comment: The safest way would be to uninstall the installed MySQL server and client, then do autoremove, then recompile your own MySQL.

Comment: @Jos : Thankyou, I will try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be rectified by the following steps

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-client-5.5 mysql-server-5.5 mysql-client-5.6 mysql-server-5.6 
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Clean the residue of the previous and the conflict installation

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
```

Install the new version
    sudo apt-get install mysql-server5.6 mysql-common mysql-client

Link and restart the apparmor

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/apparmor.d/disable/usr.sbin.mysqld
sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor restart
```

Now check the installation It will do good

Comment: @Shammerariff: Thank you pal !! Anyways I  have sorted this one long ago...

Comment: Just an hour ago I experienced this problem, I'm sorting out. So updated the resolution.